# Covariance help

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, covariance

Consider an experiment in which a fair coin is tossed 10 times in a row (the tosses are independent of each other). Let X denote the number of heads observed and let Y=X^2. Find the covariance between X and Y.

I know that Cov(x,y) = E(x*y) - E(x) * E(y) but I cannot seem to get the right answer. Any hints as to where to go from here?

Answer (score 2):

Hints:
$\operatorname{cov}(X,Y) = E[XY] - E[X]E[Y] = E[X^3] - E[X]E[X^2]$ where you should know (or be able to compute)
those last two expectations in the formula. If not, look in your textbook
for *binomial random variable* and general properties of *variance.*
It is somewhat harder to find $E[X^3]$ but you could try and find
$E[X(X-1)(X-2)]$  (**write out** the first six terms of the formula
for $E[X(X-1)(X-2)]$ without using any binomial coefficients or factorial
signs), and then use the fact that
$$E[X(X-1)(X-2)] = E[X^3 -3X^2 + 2X] = E[X^3] - 3E[X^2] + 2E[X]$$
where you know, or have just computed, the values of three of the four
expectations, and so can easily deduce the value of the fourth.